# jQuery Tools Overlay with preload delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, jquery-tools

I'm using the Overlay plugin from jQuery Tools: http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html to display a full size image when a link is clicked, but the overlay is displayed immediately and shows the image loading.
I'd like to change this behavior and wait until the image is loaded before launching the overlay. The Overlay plugin has an onBeforeLoad property to which a callback function can be attached. But, of course, the overlay display resumes as soon as this callback is executed, and will not wait for the image load event to be fired.

The plugin has a few API methods, but they don't seem very helpful for my purpose.
In my example below, the two lines I've commented out should give you an idea of what I thought might work, but doesn't.

Here's a simplified test case: http://jsfiddle.net/GlauberRocha/9jkU5/

Any idea?

```
var $trigger = $("#trigger"),
    api;

$trigger.overlay({
    fixed: true,
    mask: {
        color: "#000",
        opacity: .8
    },
    onBeforeLoad: function() {
        console.log("onBeforeLoad");
        api = $trigger.data("overlay"); // see http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html "Scripting API"
        //api.close(); // Temporarily "close" the overlay?
        setTimeout(function() { // This will be replaced by the image load event
            console.log("Waiting is over!");
            //api.load(); // Load the overlay now?
        }, 2000);
    },
    onLoad: function() {
        console.log("onLoad");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? What do you mean that it shows the image loading? Looking at your jsfiddle it seems like the overlay is working properly.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation is unclear. Yes, the overlay works fine, but I don't want to display it until the image is finished loading. In my test, the `setTimeout` just simulates what will be the `image.onload` event: I need the execution of the overlay to pause, and resume when this event is fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified my code. This version seems to work (see http://jsfiddle.net/GlauberRocha/rwtvK/). The main difference comes from the way the API method is called (`$trigger.overlay().load()` vs `$trigger.data("overlay").load()`). This inconsistency is present in the jQuery Tools docs and examples.

```
$(function () {
  var $trigger = $("#trigger");
  $trigger.overlay({
    fixed: true,
    mask: {
      color: "#000",
      opacity: .4
    },
    onBeforeLoad: function () {
      if (typeof this.init === "undefined") {
        this.init = true;
        setTimeout(function () { // This will be replaced by the image load event handler
          console.log("OK, let's show it!");
          $trigger.overlay().load(); // Load the overlay
        }, 5000);
        console.log("Not now!");
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I understand what you are wanting. To prevent the overlay from loading, you need to return false, but only if the image is not yet loaded. See if this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9jkU5/1/) helps:

```
var $trigger = $("#trigger"),
    api;

var imageLoaded = false;

$trigger.overlay({
    fixed: true,
    mask: {
        color: "#000",
        opacity: .8
    },
    onBeforeLoad: function() {
        console.log("onBeforeLoad");
        api = $trigger.data("overlay"); // see http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html "Scripting API"
        //api.close(); // Temporarily "close" the overlay?

        if(!imageLoaded){
            setTimeout(function() { // This will be replaced by the image load event 
                console.log("Waiting is over!");

               api.load(); // Load the overlay now?
            }, 2000);
            imageLoaded = true;
            return false;
        }

    },
    onLoad: function() {
        console.log("onLoad");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your solution, however I'm not sure it does exactly what I want. If the user clicks on the link and the image is not finished loading, the overlay action will simply do nothing (and the user will have to click again when the image is loaded for the overlay to appear). I want to delay the action, not cancel it (and I'll put a loader icon somewhere so the user knows something is loading).

Comment: In the jsfiddle, you only need to click the link one time. After the specified timeout completes then the overlay is loaded.

Comment: I've checked. Your code doesn't behave as I describe as I thought it would, still it doesn't work (you actually see the image loading in the opened overlay).

Comment: @GlauberRocha no problem, I am glad it helped you on your way!